# Using wp_query to pull content from a specific post using either title or id

Tags: wordpress, loops

I am trying to pull excerpts and custom fields from specific posts, I have tried using post titles and post id but I am only succeeding in pulling every single post using this query. For example I have this code trying to pull just the title for the post with id 182

```
<?php $map = new WP_Query();
$map->query('post_id=182'); ?>
<?php while ($map->have_posts()) : $map->the_post(); ?
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

It pulls the title of every single post using this method and I can not figure out how I am going to have multiple loops like this each pulling content from just one specific post. Can someone please explain where I went wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the post ID then you can use `get_post($post_id);` like so

```
$post_id = 182;
$my_post = get_post($post_id);
$title = $my_post->post_title;
echo $title;
echo $my_post->post_content;
```

ckeckout [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post)

Comment: perfect, thank you... i swear i tried this earlier and it didnt work :P

Answer (score 5):

I've had luck with `WP_query('p=182')`.